# Java Multi-Thread Pausing

Tags: java, multithreading

> My Goal

I am brand new to multi-threading in java and I am attempting to create pong.  I will only include a bit of code here that is relevant to the question.

> Problem

I want to be able to *pause* the game by pressing the space bar, and then resume it again by pressing the space bar later.  The following code works to pause the game, however it cannot resume.  All future key presses are not recognized.  It seems as if the main thread is being paused.

> Code

**Main Class**

```
public class MainManager {

    private Ticker ticker;
    private Thread tickerThread;

    private boolean active;

    public MainManager() {
        ticker = new Ticker(this,10);
        tickerThread = new Thread(ticker);

        tickerThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void tick() {
        // Does necesary things for each game tick
    }

    public void toggleState() {
        if (this.active) {
            ticker.pause();
        } else {
            this.setActive(true);
            notify();
        }
    }

    public void setActive(boolean b) {
        this.active = b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                   public void run() {
                        MainManager manager = new MainManager();
                   }
        });
    }
}
```

**Ticker Class**

```
public class Ticker implements Runnable {

    private MainManager manager;
    private int tick;

    public Ticker(MainManager manager,int tick) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.tick = tick;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        manager.setActive(true);
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.tick);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            manager.tick();
        }
    }

    public void setTickSpeed(int speed) {
        this.tick = speed;
    }   

    public synchronized void pause() {
        synchronized(manager) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for Manager");
                manager.setActive(false);
                manager.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**KeyListener Class**

***NOTE:*** *This class is added to a JFrame that is constructed inside of the MainManager constructor.  If this JFrame class is important for my question I will post the code, just let me know*

```
public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener {

    private MainManager manager;

    public KeyboardListener(MainManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("KeyPressed);
        //This line only prints on the first spacebar. 
        //After the game is paused, it never prints again.  Despite me spamming spacebar
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            manager.toggleState();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the `tickerThread` to pause and resume with the press of a key?  Any other criticisms are welcome.

Comment: Your `notify()` should be enclosed in a synchronized block.

Comment: Your `active` boolean should have the `volatile` keyword, for atomicy.

Comment: Adding `notify()` in a synchronized block did not make a difference.  In the keyListener above the line `if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {` if I put `System.out.println("Hello");` it only prints before pausing it, and never prints after I pause it even if I keep clicking spacebar.

Comment: You are suspending Swings EDT (Event dispatch thread) when you call wait(), because its in the call chain from the KeyListener (which is called on the EDT). Of course this *kills* any further event dispatching; the notify() can only come from a KeyEvent, but that also the thread thats now waiting for a notify from *itself*. You must *never* call wait() on the EDT.

Comment: @MouseEvent volatile does nothing for the atomicity of modifying a boolean. It does provide visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never left the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.

Your ticker is merrily ticking away in the other thread, which is working fine. However, if we follow the path of your toggle call, it never reaches the other thread.

Your space key is pressed->Swing EDT witchcraft->keyPressed->manager.toggleState()->ticker.pause() Now we synchronize with Manager, which isn't hard. We're still on the main thread! Then we wait.

Your space key is pressed->Swing EDT is paused. The only part of your ticker that's running in another thread is the run method.

You want to run everything relating to your game logic *off* the EDT. Run both the MainManager and the Ticker in a different thread from your JFrame and event handlers and synchronize or use a locked boolean value to send data from the IO thread to the logic thread.

Comment: @ryangoldtein Im not sure what I should change, I really am a super noob at java when it comes to anything more than basic. So I really know very little about swing, threading, event handlers, and synchronization.